# Stuck on creating a simple jQuery tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script>

             $(function() {
                $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tabs-1">
                    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. .</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-2">
                    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis..</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-3">
                    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, .</p>
                    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo</p>
                </div>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have checked the code above line by line and couldn't find the reason why it is not working. I have seen many similar examples and their code looks the same, but mine doesn't work. Can someone please help me.

Comment: I have added a simple code for tab, please let me know if that helps

Comment: The examples i have seen from people works even without css, however can you please recommend a css style for it, i dont know also how to style it.

Comment: i have added a simple tab below, please check and let me know

Comment: @fefe is saying you need to include the jqueryUI css file on your page: http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/#basic-overview-using-jquery-ui-on-a-web-page

Comment: look at here if the ui css is loaded than is working http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/ZwwX8/ you need <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to add jquery UI for simple tabs, instead use the following code

**load jquery UI styles or do the following alternative solution**

**Script .js**

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
     $('ul.header li').on("click",function(){

       $('.tab_content > div').hide();
       $('#tab-'+($(this).index()+1)).fadeIn();

       /* for adding slected class */
       $('.selected_li').removeClass('selected_li');
       $(this).addClass('selected_li');
     });
   });
</script>
```

**Style.css**

```
<style>
  .tab_content > div {
    display: none;
  }
  .tab_content > #tab-1 {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="header">
  <li class="selected_li">Nunc tincidunt</li>
  <li>Proin dolor</li>
  <li>Proin dolor</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab_content">
  <div id="tab-1" >test content 1</div>
  <div id="tab-2">test content  2</div>
  <div id="tab-3">test content  3</div>
</div> <!-- tab_content -->
```

Thanks and let me know if this helps

**UPDATE :- Do the Following Style for Better look**

```
<style>
  .tab_content > div {
    display: none;
  }
  .tab_content > #tab-1 {
    display: block;
  }

  .header {
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
  }
  .header li {
    float: left;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #036; cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px; border: 1px solid #036;
  }
  .header .selected_li {
    background: #036;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  .clear {
    clear:both;
  }
  .tab_content {
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #036;
  }
</style>
```

thanks

Comment: that is working but it is too simple style. i need it to look like this http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: -1 The question is about jQueryUI tabs, not how to roll your own HTML tabs. jQueryUI's code is robust and tested, yours is not. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @WalterStabosz  please Read the Question and then down vote, the question is stuck with jquery simple tabs, and he follows jquery UI. i just created another simple tabs with my own way.

Comment: @Wellwisher: In OP's question, he is clearly using jQueryUI's Tabs. His code calls: `$("#tabs").tabs();`. Your answer to use some hacked up tab implementation does not answer OP's question about jQueryUI Tabs. Downvote stays.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"/></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"/></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#tabs").tabs();
            });
        </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. .</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis..</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, .</p>
            <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```